# A very simple question on adjunctions that I simply can't look at correctly.

Tags: category-theory

Suppose that $\mathcal{C}$ has finite products. Why is the unit $\eta_c:c\to c\times c$ of the adjunction $\Delta\dashv \times:\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}$ the arrow $\langle 1_c,1_c\rangle$? In other words, why is $\pi_1\circ \eta_c=1_c=\pi_2\circ\eta_c$?

Answer (score 2):

The adjunction is saying that morphisms
$$(f,g) : (c,c) \to (a,b)$$
in $\mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C}$ correspond naturally with morphisms
$$h : c \to a \times b$$
in $\mathcal{C}$. This correspondence is fairly obviously given by putting $h=\langle f,g \rangle$, where $\langle f,g \rangle$ is the unique morphism $c \to a \times b$ induced by $f : c \to a$ and $g : c \to b$ by the universal property of the product. (And vice versa.)

The $c$-component of the unit is therefore the morphism corresponding to $1_{(c,c)}$. But $1_{(c,c)} = (1_c, 1_c)$, meaning that
$$\eta_c = \langle 1_c, 1_c \rangle : c \to c \times c$$
Likewise the counit is the morphism corresponding with $1_{a \times b} : a \times b \to a \times b$. But $1_{a \times b} = \langle \pi_1, \pi_2 \rangle$, and so
$$\varepsilon_{(a,b)} = (\pi_1, \pi_2) : (a \times b, a \times b) \to (a,b)$$

Comment: Hmm, thanks! I actually tried to find the explicit form of the adjunct, and, if $\phi$ is the bijection of the adjunction, and $f:c\to a$, $g:c\to b$, I found via naturality, that $$\phi(f,g)=(f\times g)\circ \eta_c$$ I struggle a bit to see why this is precisely $\langle f,g\rangle$. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Niels.Remb05: Right, and now
$$(f \times g) \circ \eta_c = (f \times g) \circ \langle 1_c, 1_c \rangle = \langle f \circ 1_c, g \circ 1_c \rangle = \langle f,g \rangle$$
Remember $f \times g = \langle f \circ \pi_1, g \circ \pi_2 \rangle$.

Comment: ... but this uses the fact that $\eta_c=\langle 1_c,1_c\rangle$, which is what I want to prove, doesn't it?...I was trying to prove that form of the adjunct, in order to prove that $\eta_c=\langle 1_c,1_c\rangle$...Isn't this your argument?

Comment: You can check adjunctions in many ways. Either find a natural isomorphism, then your unit and counit are given by what the identities map to; or define what you want to be your unit and counit and prove that they satisfy the required conditions (i.e. either they induce the appropriate natural isomorphism, or they satisfy the trangle identities, or whatever). I can't tell which way round you're working here.

Comment: So either (a) check that the isomorphism $(\mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C})((c,c),(a,b)) \cong \mathcal{C}(c,a \times b)$ given by $(f,g) \mapsto \langle f,g \rangle$ is natural in $c$ and in $(a,b)$ and find what $1_{(c,c)}$ maps to to get your unit $\eta_c$; or (b) define $\eta_c = \langle 1_c, 1_c \rangle$ and verify that the map $(f,g) \mapsto (f \times g) \circ \eta_c$ induces a natural isomorphism on hom sets. (Likewise for the counit.)

Comment: Hmm...But what if I didn't know either what the mapping is, or what the unit is. And suppose I just know, because of the definition of the product, that we must have an adjunction given by the bijection on the hom-sets as you mention it in the first line of your last comment. Then shouldn't I be able to recover that the mapping is $(f,g)\mapsto \langle f,g\rangle$ or that the unit is $\eta_c=\langle 1_c,1_c\rangle$?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you know what the bijection is then you can recover the unit.

Comment: I mean, the fact that $a\times b$ is a limit, says that we have an iso $\hom(\Delta c,(a,b))\cong (c,a\times b)$, natural in $c$ and $(a,b)$. This satisfies the requirements for an adjunction between $\Delta$ and $\times$. But by the data I just gave, I have no clue about what the bijection actually looks like. What I was trying to ask is, can you recover the fact that the isomorphism is the mapping $(f,g)\mapsto \langle f,g\rangle$ just from this data? This is what I was trying to do in my first reply, where I proved that $\phi(f,g)=(f\times g)\circ\eta_c$. Now why is this of the above form?